# In Linux, why does my battery last only 4 hours instead of the usual 10?

Tags: linux, battery, hibernate

I decided to switch from Windows 7 (10 hours of battery work, suspend/hibernate modes work great - Asus U36Jc) to some Linux.

- First there was Ubuntu 11.04 (with all current updates) – 4 hours of work, suspend/hibernate modes didn't work (black screen not reacting to any input, requiring reboot). Disabling NVIDIA graphics card didn't help, enabling it again also didn't help.
- Then there was CentOS 6 (with all updates) – same problem, 4 hours of work, suspend/hibernate modes don't work (requiring reboot).

So the question is, is this a problem with these distributions, the laptop or its stupid owner? Do other distributions have the same problem and how can I resolve it?

I still think that the problem is that the laptop has two graphic cards ndash; the Intel graphics and the NVIDIA card, but disabling NVIDIA doesn't help.

Comment: Have you recompiled the kernel with some vendor specific patches that are particular to your battery?

Comment: You probably want to check out http://linux.slashdot.org/story/11/04/22/2132251/Linux-Kernel-Suffering-Power-Management-Regression which describes bad power management under the kernel that shipped with Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Well the first thought is that in Linux You might have some heavy background work in a background working all the time by default (e.g. file indexer or smth like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution — it's the NVIDIA graphic card.

It didn't work with Ubuntu because Ubuntu 11.04 itself [has a problem with battery life](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/11/04/22/2132251/Linux-Kernel-Suffering-Power-Management-Regression) so switching off the graphics card didn't help a lot.

I disabled it in CentOS 6 and the battery life went to about 10 hours again.